# Returning factorials in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, factorial

I'm trying to create a script that returns the factorial of the input number as part of a challenge. When I try to run it, it returns the proper factorial, but apparently I did it wrong somehow.

It looks like this:

```
function FirstFactorial(num) { 
    if (num > 1) {
    var x = num;
    for (var i = 1; i < x; i++) {
      num = num * i;
    }
  } else if (num === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    console.log("That's not a number!");
  }
  return num;
}
```

Then I tried doing it like this, but it still doesn't work!

```
function FirstFactorial(num) { 

  if (num < 0) {
    num = 0;
    console.log("You have to input a number!");
  }

  if (num === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  return num * FirstFactorial(num - 1);
}
```

Comment: You say it works, but "I did it wrong somehow" ... tell us more?

Comment: *"but apparently I did it wrong somehow."* What does this mean?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. ***Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.***"

Comment: The website that I am using (coderbyte.com) tells me that I didn't do the task correctly... I am as confused as you are.

Comment: @AskeOfir We are not confused at all. The only thing that confuses us is your 'question'.

Comment: Why is there `var x= num;` any use?

Comment: The code might work, BUT, have you parsed the number coming from the Input using `parseInt()`  function? @AskeOfir

Comment: [link]http://i.imgur.com/It8XCAI.png

Comment: @SashiKant: The loop following would never end if the OP hadn't used `x`.

Comment: ohh sorry, didnt see that :)

Comment: @LlogariCasas I am not familiar with that function. How do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that they expected and intended you to use recursion (a function that calls itself).

If you think about factorials, each builds on the result of the previous one, which is the classic case for using recursion.

*(Note that I'm specifically **not** posting code doing this with recursion, because presumably the point here is for **you** to work out how to do it.)*